# Navigating with the cursor in MS Word in multiple page view

Tags: navigation, ms-word, cursor

Ok. I find this annoying, maybe someone knows how to get around this.

When I'm working in Word 2010, in print layout it automatically switches to showing multiple pages if I zoom out to much. But since I have a big monitor and I do not like giant sized letters, I keep fighting this setting. When I'm zoomed out at a pleasant level, I have two pages side-by-side.

This two page layout is fine, but only for one thing: when I'm at the top of a page on the right side and I press cursor up, the cursor does not move to the bottom of the previous page (on the left), but to the bottom of the page visually above it, thus skipping one page.

This is very frustrating; I'm massaging the text, need to navigate the lines around the current, but I keep grabbing the mouse to get my cursor where I want to. Yes, I know I can switch to the "conceptual" view, but I like seeing how my text really looks on the page (WYSIWYG).

Can I either convince Word in print layout to show only one page at that zoom level, or can I modify the cursor behavior to go to the previous page instead of the one above?

Comment: I'm sure someone will close this as not programming related, but I too find navigation counter intuitive when multiple pages are displayed.

Comment: Would it help to know that the document I was writing was a functional design document? :-) It may not be programming related, but a lot of programmers use Word.

Comment: You might want to comment on http://blogs.office.com/b/office-next/archive/2012/07/26/reading-in-the-new-office.aspx

Comment: I added a comment on that article; if they're going to introduce a reading mode, then quirky navigation in edit mode (that seem to be related to easy reading) should be optimized for editing.